# How to Develop Android video streaming application with diffrent video qualities as in Youtube (Change Quality)

Tags: android, video, streaming

I would like to develop a android app with video player that renders diffrent qualities of same video just like in youtube change quality feature.

Proir to that i am curious to know whether the source should contain videos of all the qulity options provided to render them dynamically.

Any help is sincerly appreciated.

My code to dtream video from URL.

public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoViewDemo";

```
private VideoView mVideoView;
private EditText mPath;
private ImageButton mPlay;
private ImageButton mPause;
private ImageButton mReset;
private ImageButton mStop;
private String current;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

    mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
    mPath.setText("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");

    mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    mReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            playVideo();
        }
    });
    mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.pause();
            }
        }
    });
    mReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });
    mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                current = null;
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    });
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            playVideo();

        }

    });
}

private void playVideo() {
    try {
        final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
        if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(VideoViewDemo.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
            if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            current = path;
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }
}

private String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException {
    if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
        return path;
    } else {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");
        temp.deleteOnExit();
        String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
        do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);
            if (numread <= 0)
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        } while (true);
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return tempPath;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: I have tried basic video streaming application using VideoView class but not sure of changing the quality of the video. By the way i am quite new to this technology. Thanks.

Comment: Post here what have you tried.

Comment: Please see above i have posted my code to stream video from url.

Comment: Hi got it solved by below methods on setOnClickListener event get the current postion of videow view and change the video source to HD and use SeekTo method with current position and then start HD video so that HD video cans tart from current postion of previous SD video.

Answer (score 0):

Hi got it solved by below methods on setOnClickListener event get the current postion of videow view and change the video source to HD and use SeekTo method with current position and then start HD video so that HD video cans tart from current postion of previous SD video.